# How can I Alias Table name?

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, alias, tablename

I am using  `PostGreSql as database`, I have `tables in pgAdmin`.

I want to set as `alias` to table `myData`. I have tried using `AS` or `ALIAS` but nothing works for me.

Here is my class

```
class Product extends Model{
constructor(conn, schema){
        super(conn, schema, "product", {
                // fields
       },true);
   }

 // function
  async getNextData() {
   try {
   const data = await this._conn.query(`
   select  *
   from  ${this._schema}."terms", ${this._schema}."myData"  ------>>>> ALIAS THIS TABLE
   where (${this._schema}."myData"."firstName" = ${this._schema}."yourData"."lastName")}
 }
}
```

Comment: try this
select d.firstname from myData d

Comment: You mean `${this._schema}."myData d"`?

Comment: yes, try this once.

Comment: This did not work, any other approach? Thanks

Comment: Moreover I want to get access in `WHERE` clause